# Java Synchronized Methods

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a number  of shared variable x,y,z, all of which can modified in two different methods running in two different threads.(say method 1 in thread 1  and method 2 in thread 2) . If I declare these two methods as synchronized , does it guarantee the consistency of the variables x,y and z. Or should I separately use a lock on each of those variables?

Comment: `synchronized` is applied on instances not methods.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad ... which means that the results will be consistent. Dare to write an answer?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: That's true, but you can also declare a method to be synchronized. It inserts an implicit `synchronized (this)` around the body of the method.

Comment: Also, you must not only synchronize the code blocks which *modify* the variables, but also the code blocks which *read* the variables.

Comment: Are you describing a single class here? One class containing the variables mentioned and the two methods?

Comment: @duncan: no two different classes.. Suppose Class A has a static variable, that is modified by a method in Class A as well as a method in Class B. . then is it safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is subjective. The behaviour depends on the way you instantiate your threads. If two threads call the synchtonized methods on the same instance of the class containing these methods, they will block. If each thread instantiates a new object of the class containing the methods, they will not block since there will be two locks on two different instances of the class.

Comment: But is blocking *bad*? Deadlocking certainly is. Invalid reads of variable certainly are!

Comment: When i say blocking, I mean waiting to acquire the lock. Thats why synchronization was introduced in the first place, to stop threads from jumping around in an unpredictable manner and to avoid race conditions. There wont be any invalid reads if your threads lock on a single instance.

Comment: @bot: Thanks. So what is the solution. Individual locks on the variables?

Comment: You cant aquire locks on a variable.The solution is to make sure that all threads use the same instance of a class so that the synchronized methods in the class will make the threads behave and not jump around. You should upvote an answer when it solves your problem :)

Comment: @Bot: "You can't acquire locks on a variable". That's somewhat misleading. The `synchronized` keyword obtains the *monitor* for an object. If a method is declared synchronized then it implicitly obtains the monitor for `this` for the duration of the method. It's perfectly acceptable to have a synchronized block that obtains the monitor for a different variable.

Comment: @Bot: This is not subjective, nor does it depend on how the threads are instantiated. The behaviour of `synchronized` is well-defined in the language spec, and how you obtain the Thread objects is irrelevant. If two threads access different objects then there is no way there can be a race condition or an invalid read. So we only need to consider the case where two threads access the same object. So long as critical sections (i.e. reads/writes to shared data) are protected by synchronization on an appropriate object there will not be a problem.

Comment: @Cameron : I hope you know that locking happens on an object and not on a variable. Even though you can have a synchronized block with a reference variable, the actual lock is acquired on the object and not the reference variable. I hope you understand what I mean by "locks can be acquired on objects only".

Comment: If you read the OP's comments on all the answers and if you read the question again, you will realize that the OP was talking about two classes sharing the same variables. That is why i felt the need to explain that the object must be shared by the threads. Its clear from the OPs comments that my explanation was necessary and making assumptions is something i dont like doing :)

Comment: @Cameron : Check the OPs comments on your answer. He clearly specifies that the two methods are in different classes and share a public variable (which kinda sucks )

Comment: @Bot: Yes, of course I understand that the lock is obtained on the object. I thought that was clear when I talked about how it obtains the monitor for an object (that's how it *really* works - it doesn't lock the object itself, it locks the monitor). I also note that the question itself does not mention that the methods are in different classes. It is clarified in the comments.

Comment: Read the OPs comment on this answer. He asks "Individual locks on the variables". Dont you think my clarrification is absolutely necessary for the sake of OPs understanding?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your approach will guarantee consistency, assuming those variables are all private and are not accessed (read or write) outside of the two synchronized methods.

Note that if you read those variables outside of a synchronized block then you could get inconsistent results:

```
class Foo {
    private int x;

    public synchronized void foo() {
        x = 1;
    }

    public synchronized void bar() {
        x = 2;
    }

    public boolean baz() {
        int a = x;
        int b = x;
        // Unsafe! x could have been modified by another thread between the two reads
        // That means this method could sometimes return false
        return a == b;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Updated to address your comment about the static variable.

Each class should own its own data. If class `A` allows direct access to a variable (by making it public) then it is not owning its own data and it becomes very difficult to enforce thread safety.

If you do this:

```
class A {
    private static int whatever;

    public static synchronized int getWhatever() {
        return whatever;
    }

    public static synchronized void setWhatever(int newWhatever) {
        whatever = newWhatever;
    }
}
```

then you'll be fine.

Remember that `synchronized` enforces a mutex on a single object. For synchronized methods it's `this` (or the Class object for static methods). Synchronized blocks on other objects will not interfere.

```
class A {
    public synchronized void doSomething() {...}
}
class B {
    public synchronized void doSomethingElse() {...}
}
```

A call to `doSomething` will not wait for calls to `doSomethingElse` because they're synchronized on different objects: in this case, the relevant instance of `A` and the relevant instance of `B`. Similarly, two calls to `doSomething` on different instances of `A` will not interfere.

I highly recommend that you take a look at [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601). It is an excellent book that explains all the subtleties of the Java thread and memory models.

Comment: Are you sure? What if each thread instantiates a new Foo? Gotcha?

Comment: @cameron: Suppose if the foo() method is in class foo and the bar() method is in a different class say class bar. Suppose the variable x is not private and I modify it in both the methods foo() and bar(). Then does it ensure consistency?

Comment: @Ashwin No it doesnt. See my answer. Consistency can only be ensured if the lock is obtained on the same object.

Comment: @bot: Thanks. So what is the solution. Individual locks on the variables?

Comment: @bot: Gotcha? No. If each thread instantiates a new Foo then they won't interfere with each other. `x` is an instance variable, so if there are different instances of Foo then they each have their own `x`. There's no need to worry about thread safety if each object is accessed by exactly one thread.

Comment: That is exactly what I am saying and that is exactly what i said in my answer. The OP needs to understand how locks work to truly appreciate the synchronized keyword

Comment: Worth noting that instances of `A` should use the synchronized getters and setters rather than directly accessing `A.whatever`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will be consistent.

> A synchronized method acquires a monitor (§17.1) before it executes.
>   For a class (static) method, the monitor associated with the Class
>   object for the method's class is used. For an instance method, the
>   monitor associated with this (the object for which the method was
>   invoked) is used.

Check out this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6)

**Note:-** *One point you have to be careful about (several programmers generally fall in that trap) is that there is no link between synchronized static methods and sync'ed non static methods*

Comment: Are you sure? What if each thread instantiates a new instance of the class containing the methods the thread will call?

Comment: @bot: if that was the case, then the OP wouldn't have shared variables being modified by different threads, as the question says.

Comment: The OP was talking about 2 different instances of 2 diferent classes sharing a variable as opposed to a single instance of a classs being shared with 2 threads. Your answer doesn't address the OP's question and is incorrect as can be justified by my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you synchronize on methods :

1. If method is `static`, the lock will be taken on the `class` object
2. If method is `non-static`, the lock will be taken on the `instance` object.

As long as the lock is taken only by one thread at one time, yes it is consistent and safe to do what you intend to.